# Center large wallpaper in small browser

Tags: html, css

I have a very large wallpaper (1920x1080 - Full HD) on my site, and I want it to center to the middle of the screen, instead of the left side, if the browser window is smaller than the image.

My current markup looks like this:

```
<div id="wallpaper">
  <img />
</div>
```

And the styles are:

```
div#wallpaper
{
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

div#wallpaper img
{
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

I'm using an img tag, because I load it async through jquery, and I'm using position absolute on the parent div to ensure it stays out of the page flow. Finally my content is positioned on top of it with z-index higher than 1.

The problem with the above is, when you browser is only 1024x768 you'll just see the left side of the image - I want it to be the middle portion.

Meaning it should crop from both left and right sides, when the wallpaper is larger than the browser window.

Hope all this made sense, otherwise please ask :-)

Comment: `background-image` is not an option? Because it would be dead easy with that.

Comment: The img tag is mostly for the async loading, as the wallpaper is quite large (~300kb). It's in order to not slow down the page too much. But then again most people have decent connections now a days, so if you have a solution using background-image, please post it and I'll give a go :-)

Comment: @Karpie's answer will work fine, although I think it needs `center center` to achieve the desired effect... Anyway, you'll work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do is possible, the way you're doing it.

What I would do is set the image to be the background-image of the wallpaper div, and then set the background position to center the image.

eg.

`<div id="wallpaper" style="background-image: foo.jpg"></div>`

and in CSS...

```
div#wallpaper
{
    background-position: top 50%;
}
```

Comment: This seems like the same Pekka suggested. And it does work excellently, so I'll stick with it.